# Missing Connector Pieces

Tags: reverse-engineering

There are missing connector pieces in this PCB that I was working on and I swear that there was no connector there in the first place, so I ruled out me going insane.I circled the connectors in gray.  Are these connector pieces for something else off the board I have?

[image]

**PCB Details**

This PCB belongs to a Sharp 1999 TV.  Was connected to four other small PCB one the buttons for the TV, the other the jacks on the TV, the speakers, and deflection coil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may or not be used by your specific tv. But it is not uncommon for a pcb to have a populated but unused internal connector. The same board may be used in multiple model tvs or with different but equal modular parts (power supplies, output boards etc) so they use a general board. Design once and use in modular fashion as needed.

It could also be a debug or test  interface.

Good luck.